# Make 2D particle system in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, particles

SO I saw a tutorial online how to make a particle system, and I made it. Only thing is, I want to use it for a 2D Menu. So when I add the particles in front of the canvas, they don't show up in 2D. How do I make particles that will show up on a 2D menu?

Comment: How about positioning the Canvas in world space, and moving it behind the particle system?

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. Please post your comment as an answer and I will award it.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the Canvas to World Space? If you did, it should just end up positioned like all the other objects in the scene, meaning it won't be constrained to the camera and should shift if you move the camera. Here's a [guide on how to do it](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).

Comment: Just did it, it worked! Please post your comment as an answer and I will award it.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try positioning your `Canvas` in World Space, then moving it behind the particle system. This will allow the `Canvas` to be positioned like all the other objects in your scene, and no longer be constrained to the camera.

Here's a [guide from Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html) on how to do it.